# Spring Validator to compare date with another one in the database

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I want to write a validator, that will check if user is old enough to be another user's parent. So, for example, I have this code, where I get the form information and can check for errors:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/setParent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView setParent(@Valid @ModelAttribute("person") Person parent, BindingResult bindingResult,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    logger.info("set parent controller");
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("index", "parent", parent);
    } else {
        String personName = request.getParameter("personName");
        String relation = request.getParameter("relation");
        Person person = new Person(personName, null);
        int pID = databaseModel.getPersonID(person);
        int parentID = databaseModel.getPersonID(parent);
        int rID = databaseModel.getRelationID(relation);
        databaseModel.insertRelation(pID, parentID, rID);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("setParentSuccess");
        modelAndView.addObject("parent", databaseModel.getPersonTree(parentID));
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

I have started to write a custom validator:

```
    @Documented
    @Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Constraint(validatedBy = CheckOlderThanValidator.class)
    @Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
    public @interface OlderThan {
    String message() default "my custom validator";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}


    public class CheckOlderThanValidator implements ConstraintValidator<OlderThan, Date> {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseModel model;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Date date, ConstraintValidatorContext arg1) {
            return false;   
    }

}
```

but then realized that I can not get a second user date to this validator to compare. How is it done? Thank you

Comment: Generally speaking, Bean Validation is expected to verify that a particular object has some sort of internally consistent state, not to validate it with an external mutable data source. I would normally expect to see this sort of logic implemented in your business tier, throwing a custom subclass of `IllegalStateException` (-> HTTP 422) if there's a problem.

Comment: all right, what is the correct way of dealing with such check? Could you explain it in a language for noobs with example? So, in this case, should I make a comparison inside the controller method and insert the errors into ModelAndView or any other method?

Comment: You should do it inside your *business service*. Following the Single Responsibility Principle, Spring MVC Web controllers should only be responsible for translating Web requests into business calls (so `personService.create(person)`, for example); all business logic, such as checking for consistency with the system, goes in your service. (Note also that you *really* need to read the docs about Spring MVC's parameter-binding features, as you never need to `getParameter` yourself; it's one of the most powerful tools Spring offers.)